# How to assign a variable in an IF condition, and then return it?

Tags: python, if-statement, variable-assignment

```
def isBig(x):
   if x > 4: 
       return 'apple'
   else: 
       return 'orange'
```

This works:

```
if isBig(y): return isBig(y)
```

This does NOT work:

```
if fruit = isBig(y): return fruit
```

Why doesn't the 2nd one work!? I want a 1-liner. Except, the 1st one will call the function TWICE.

*How to make it 1 liner, without calling the function twice?*

Comment: Why do you want a one-liner? Programs do not get better because they have fewer lines.

Comment: Same as http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1513436/what-should-i-use-instead-of-assignment-in-an-expression-in-python/1513987#1513987

Comment: You have 100's of these? You wouldn't happen to be writing a parser, would you?  See this list (http://nedbatchelder.com/text/python-parsers.html) from Ned Batchelder's website.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

I see somebody else has already pointed to my old "assign and set" Cookbook recipe, which boils down in its simplest version to:

```
class Holder(object):
   def set(self, value):
     self.value = value
     return value
   def get(self):
     return self.value

h = Holder()

...

if h.set(isBig(y)): return h.get()
```

However, this was intended mostly to ease transliteration between Python and languages where assignment is directly supported in `if` or `while`. If you have "hundreds" of such check-and-return in a cascade, it's *much* better to do something completely different:

```
hundreds = isBig, isSmall, isJuicy, isBlah, ...

for predicate in hundreds:
  result = predicate(y)
  if result: return result
```

or even something like

```
return next(x for x in (f(y) for f in hundreds) if x)
```

if it's OK to get a StopIteration exception if no predicate is satisfied, or

```
return next((x for x in (f(y) for f in hundreds) if x)), None)
```

if `None` is the proper return value when no predicate is satisfied, etc.

Almost invariably, using (or even wishing for;-) the `Holder` trick/non-idiom is a "design smell" which suggests looking for a different and more Pythonic approach -- the one case where `Holder` is justified is exactly the special case for which I designed it, i.e., the case  where you want to keep close correspondence between the Python code and some non-Python (you're transliterating a reference algorithm in Python and want it working first before refactoring it into a more Pythonic form, or you're writing Python as a prototype that will be transliterated into C++, C#, Java, etc, once it's working effectively).

Answer (score 174):

Starting `Python 3.8`, and the introduction of [assignment expressions (PEP 572)](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0572/) (`:=` operator), it's now possible to capture the condition value (`isBig(y)`) as a variable (`x`) in order to re-use it within the body of the condition:

```
if x := isBig(y): return x
```

Answer (score 9):

The one liner doesn't work because, in Python, assignment (`fruit = isBig(y)`) is a statement, not an expression. In C, C++, Perl, and countless other languages it is an expression, and you can put it in an `if` or a `while` or whatever you like, but not in Python, because the creators of Python thought that this was too easily misused (or abused) to write "clever" code (like you're trying to).

Also, your example is rather silly. `isBig()` will always evaluate to `true`, since the only string that's false is the empty string (`""`), so your `if` statement is useless in this case. I assume that's just a simplification of what you're trying to do. Just do this:

```
tmp = isBig(y)
if tmp: return tmp
```

Is it really that much worse?

Comment: Thank you.

By the way, when you have 100 like this, it is much worse :)

Comment: When you have 100 lines like this, it sounds a bit like your solution is sub-optimal, but I can't speak without knowing what you're doing.

Comment: At the very least, feed your test cases into a list and iterate over it to avoid writing them all out like that.

Comment: What if it's an `elif`?

Comment: @xuhdev I would expect `elif` to have the same behaviour as `if`.

Comment: _Is it really much worse?_ - it messes up the flow somewhat in a set of `elif` cases. It would be (and apparently is in 3.8) nice to have an `elif` check some complex conditional that requires a function call and have the result visible to the body of the `elif` block.

Answer (score 3):

You could use a generator:

```
def ensure(x):
    if x: yield x

for fruit in ensure(isBig(y)):
    return fruit
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the assignment operation cannot be evaluated as having a boolean value. The `if` statement relies on being able to evaluate a boolean. For example,

```
>>> fruit = 'apple'
>>> bool(fruit = 'apple')
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)

/Users/jem/<ipython console> in <module>()

TypeError: 'fruit' is an invalid keyword argument for this function
>>> bool('a')
True
```

Comment: (I didn't downvote, but) The lack of a boolean return isn't the _cause_ of the inability to use it in an `if()` statement. Both of these limitations are _side-effects_ of the language defining assignment as a statement rather than an expression.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to code in PHP (or C), code in it. Don't try to force its methods onto another language.

One of the basic tenets behind Python (in my opinion) is its readability. You should be using:

```
fruit = isBig(y)
if fruit: return fruit
```

I should also mention that your use of `isXXX()` is very strange; it's usually used to return boolean values. Especially in this case where you're using it in an `IF` statement.

Comment: I don't consider either version more or less readable, but perhaps that's from experience. Also, IMHO it's more _consistent_ to make it an expression, since `=` looks like (and is parsed, both by interpreters and humans, as) an operator (implicit expression), rather than a function (implicit statement, though this isn't technically true).

Comment: Frankly you can't always use the language you want to for a project, making this one of the least helpful answers I have ever seen. If I could vote you down a dozen times, I would.

Comment: Rabbit, if you're required to use a specific language for whatever reason, you should use it properly. Trying to shoehorn other-language constructs is a stupid idea. I've seen such bizarre things as `#define begin {` in C code because Pascal programmers didn't want to adapt. That sort of behaviour makes the code useless in _both_ languages.