# Add custom method to string object

Tags: python, ruby

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can I add custom methods/attributes to built-in Python types?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4698493/can-i-add-custom-methods-attributes-to-built-in-python-types)

In Ruby you can override any built-in object class with custom method, like this:

```
class String
  def sayHello
    return self+" is saying hello!"
  end
end                              

puts 'JOHN'.downcase.sayHello   # >>> 'john is saying hello!'
```

How can i do that in python? Is there a normally way or just hacks?

Comment: This has just been answered in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4698493/can-i-add-custom-methods-attributes-to-built-in-python-types/4698550#4698550 . Suggest closing.

Comment: Monkeypatching is possible but has limits, as pointed out in that question (and even more). I recommend just defining a "free" function that does this.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

You can't because the builtin-types are coded in C. What you can do is subclass the type:

```
class string(str):
    def sayHello(self):
        print(self, "is saying 'hello'")
```

Test:

```
>>> x = string("test")
>>> x
'test'
>>> x.sayHello()
test is saying 'hello'
```

You could also overwrite the str-type with `class str(str):`, but that doesn't mean you can use the literal `"test"`, because it is linking to the builtin `str`.

```
>>> x = "hello"
>>> x.sayHello()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#10>", line 1, in <module>
    x.sayHello()
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'sayHello'
>>> x = str("hello")
>>> x.sayHello()
hello is saying 'hello'
```

Answer (score 3):

The normal Python equivalent to this is to write a function that takes a string as it's first argument:

```
def sayhello(name):
    return "{} is saying hello".format(name)

>>> sayhello('JOHN'.lower())
'john is saying hello'
```

Simple clean and easy. Not everything has to be a method call.

Comment: The disadvantage of this approach is that you can't write a mutator method. For example, today I want a method `str.startswithThenRemove(p)` that mutates `str` to remove the optional prefix `p` and then returns `True` if the prefix was found and `False` if it wasn't:  `if option.startswithThenRemove("--foo="): handleFoo(option)`. You can't do that in any easy way in Python (but see http://stackoverflow.com/a/1551223/1424877).

Comment: Even if you could add a custom method to a string you still wouldn't be able to write a mutator method: Python strings are immutable.

Comment: Except this method is neither clean not easy. Ugly af, at least compared to what OP provided