# Ruby add method!(with exclamation mark) to string

Tags: ruby, methods

I have found many resources how to do add "ordinary" method to String.

ie [Add custom method to string object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4699179/add-custom-method-to-string-object)

But i haven't found any info how to add "destructive" method with exclamation mark to String class.

Can somebody rewrite this method to "destructive one"?

```
def nextval
  case self
  when "A"
    return "B"
  when "B"
    return "C"
  # etc
  end
end
```

[this example is very simple, i want to add more complex method to String]

I want to achive something like `sub` and `sub!` methods.

Comment: You'll need to be more specific.  You can probably only mutate the things that are exposed publicly, unless you delve into private APIs, which most likely will just come back to haunt you ;)

Comment: Do you mean you want to *change* the value of `self` to "B", "C", etc?

Comment: Ah, I see what you're after...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just use the destructive methods already provided by String.

```
def nextval!
  case self
  when "A"
    replace("B")
  when "B"
    replace("C")
  # etc
  end
end
```

Comment: Wow it works. :) Thanks. +1 and accept(have to wait 4 min..).

Answer (score 1):

There is such method - String#next!

```
a = "foo"
a.next! # => "fop"
puts a  # => "fop"
```

Comment: I know. But I writed that code just for example. I want to add more complex method.

Comment: For 'destructive' method you should add exclamation mark at the end of name method (that's just a convention) and to make some changes to 'self'. But not all methods with ! at the end are the destructive one, i.e. 'at_exit!', so that mark usually indicates that the method should be used cautiously.