# Creating custom string type in Python

Tags: python, string, class, unicode

In Python, is there an option to create a custom string class, that could be created by typing something like:

```
a = b"some string"
a.someCustomMethod()
```

Just like python has its `u""` and `r""` strings?

Comment: What are you hoping to accomplish this way?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Add custom method to string object](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4699179/add-custom-method-to-string-object)

Comment: I'm trying to make using my type of string VERY easy for the users of my library.

Comment: First I thought this was about [`typing.NewType`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#newtype), but actually it seems to be about basic OOP in python.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's straightforward to write your own string class, but you can't get the construction syntax you want. The closest you can get is

```
a = MyString("some string")
```

where `MyString` is your custom class. I suppose you can alias `b = MyString` if you want.

Also, note that `b"some string"` is already the bytestring literal syntax. In Python 2, it just makes a regular string. In Python 3, it makes a `bytes` object, since regular strings are unicode in Python 3.

Comment: Note that you can subclass `str` or `UserString` to create `MyString` and gain all the properties you'd expect from a normal string in addition to your new property. See http://docs.python.org/2.7/library/userdict.html?#module-UserString and http://stackoverflow.com/a/4699190/1970751