# How to rewrite a user-defined function and change it to a user defined-method?

Tags: python, class, methods, user-defined-functions

I have a user defined function in the code below. Is there a way for me to re-write it with different syntax where I don't use brackets around the variable I want but rather have the function as a method such as .printfunction. Is there a way using classes and methods to rewrite the function as a method rather than a user-defined function?

The desired output needs to be xY .

```
def printfunction(var2):
    return "x" + var2

printfunction("Y")

def printfunction(var2):
    return "x" + var2

#Desired Syntax
var1 = "x"
var1.printfunction("Y")
```

Comment: You have to create a class and make that function a class method.

Comment: How do I do that? I am relatively new to python and am really confused. Thanks

Comment: "_I am relatively new to python_": Learn one bit at a time. Online courses, textbooks, tutorials. That's the only proper way.

Comment: Not sure why anyone would downvote this question. Check here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4699179/add-custom-method-to-string-object for a better answer than I can give but in essence, you can't (in Python) override a string in the way you want. You can create a new class as @DYZ says and the link should help.

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html

Comment: Thank you so much @grayson . Really appreciate it!!!

Comment: Thank you so much @Patrick Artner . Really appreciate it !!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure what version of python you are running on but this one works for me.

```
class String():
    def __init__(self,str):
        self.str = str
    def printfunction(self,append_this):
        print(self.str + append_this)


var1 = String('x')
var1.printfunction('Y')
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to the advice from @grayson and @Patrick Artner. I am able to answer my question

```
class Strgcust(str):
     def printfunction(self, var1):
             return (self + var1)

var1 = Strgcust("x")

var1.printfunction(str("Y"))
```

Comment: Python has a built-in module named `string`, so it would be a good idea to name your class something else—`String` would avoid the problem and be in accordance with the advice in [PEP 8 - Naming Conventions](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#naming-conventions) which says class names should have their first letter Capitalized.