# How can I execute my function to strings like this: `string.func()`

Tags: python

Lets supose I have a function that makes add bigger spaces to my text.

```py
def bigger_spaces(text):
    text = list(text)
    print(' '.join(text))
```

To execute it, i need to do `bigger_spaces(my_text)`. how can I execute like this:

```
my_text.bigger_spaces()
```

I know I can make a class but then I have to add the string to that class first

Comment: I'd probably subclass `str` and then make `text` an instance of that class, rather than modifying the built-in `str` class.

Comment: Note that while it's considered a reasonable practice (in some quarters, not by any means all) to extend classes that shipped with the standard library in Ruby, that is not *at all* considered a responsible thing to do in Python... arguably more on account of cultural issues than actual runtime differences (there's a lot more appreciation for readability, predictability, maintainability, etc in the Python world).

Comment: create a class that has a function "bigger_spaces()" and a text as one property of that class then create object "my_text" as an instance of that class.

Comment: @JammyDodger but in this case he had to add the string to the class, I don't want to do it this way. Is there a way I can do it to all strings without having to add them to the class?

Comment: @rafa_rrayes, just because the other instance got an answer you don't like doesn't mean it wasn't the same question being asked. The answer is "no, you can't" -- intentionally so; in the Python world, we consider this kind of practice to be dangerous, inasfar as monkeypatching makes it harder to understand what code does on a read (increasing the amount of context that needs to be read and understood), even when it's putatively interacting only with built-in types.

Comment: Also Python isn't designed to support adding methods to built-in classes, and trying to brute-force it is a recipe for weird segfaults and memory corruption.

Answer (score 1):

```
class MyString:
    def __init__(self, string):
        self.string = string
    def bigger_string(self):
        print(' '.join(self.string))

mystring = MyString("this is the string")
mystring.bigger_string()
```

output

```
t h i s   i s   t h e   s t r i n g
```

Dataclass in Python 3.7

```
from dataclasses import dataclass

@dataclass
class St:

    text : str

    def bigger(self) -> None:
        self.text = list(self.text)
        print(" ".join(self.text))

mys = St("Hello")
mys.bigger()
```

output

```
H e l l o
```

Comment: Consider adding this answer [on the canonical instance of the question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4699179/add-custom-method-to-string-object), rather than here; that way, it's going to get a wider audience, and we avoid having folks' attention spread across multiple instances of the question where it could be focused on just one.