# Evaluating result of expression in if-statement in python

Tags: python, syntax

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to assign a variable in IF, and then return it. (Python)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1550134/how-to-assign-a-variable-in-if-and-then-return-it-python)

In Python is there a better way to do this?:

```
myVal = getVal()

if not myVal:
    continue
```

I'd like to do something like this:

```
if not (myVal = getVal()):
    continue
```

But that is not valid syntax.  Are there any other ways to do this on one line like can be done in PHP and Perl?

Comment: Python highly values clarity of code. You should not do this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Its not pythonic to have return value for assignment. In python, assignment means binding object to a name, not putting value in memory location.

Answer (score 1):

No, you can't do this.

I'd say that's because it's too easy to confuse with `if not (myVal == getVal()):`.

Answer (score 0):

No you can't do this.

However, almost all situations like this can be done more cleanly in python. However, in order to show you how to do that we need more context. In particular, how this loop you are continuing is constructed.

Answer (score 0):

You could try this instead, (depending on what `getVal` can return):

```
if not getVal():
    continue
```