# Python assigning value in return statement

Tags: python, arrays, recursion

I am learning Python and I want to rewrite this C code.

```c
int rec(int n, int *a , int *b) {
   return n == 1 ? *a = *b : rec(n / 2, b, a) + rec((n + 1) / 2, a + n / 2, b + n / 2);
}

int main(void) {
   int a[] = { 5, 9, 9, 6, 4, 0 };
   int b[] = { 1, 7, 2, 9, 2, 0 };
   printf("%d %d", rec(5, a, b), rec(6, b, a));
   return 0;
}
```

To Python:

```py
def rec(n, a, b):
    if n == 1:
        a=b
        return a
    else:
        return rec(n / 2, b, a) + rec((n + 1) / 2, a + n / 2, b + n / 2)

a = [5, 9, 9, 6, 4, 0];
b = [1, 7, 2, 9, 2, 0];

print(rec(5, a, b))
```

But it always returns syntax error in `a = b` statement. What did I do wrong?

Edit: Now, as I fixed code it throws:

```
 File "main.py", line 13, in <module>                                                                                    
    print(rec(5,a,b))                                                                                                     
  File "main.py", line 8, in rec                                                                                          
    return rec(n/2,b,a) + rec((n+1)/2,a+n/2,b+n/2)                                                                        
  File "main.py", line 8, in rec                                                                                          
    return rec(n/2,b,a) + rec((n+1)/2,a+n/2,b+n/2)                                                                        
TypeError: can only concatenate list (not "int") to list
```

Comment: Your question is not about C.

Comment: What do you expect `a=b` to return? If you want to do a boolean comparison you need to return `a==b` since `a=b` would assign `a` to `b`. Returning of an assignment does not make sense hence the error occurs.

Comment: Do you understand the C code?

Comment: Oh god, who upvote these? @albert: It's perfectly fine to expect it to work (and return the result of the assignment) if you're coming from a different language. Python doesn't allow it because it's a common source of error (typo). And... he clearly *doesn't* want comparison.

Comment: i understand the C code , but as i said my python skillz are very low. How could i rewrite it in python correctly then?

Comment: @KarolyHorvath: I took a look at the python code first in order to get rid of any error messages. Since I am not that skilled in different languages I didn't know that there might be languages where you are able to return an assignment. Sorry for that.

Comment: @Hitori: Maybe you could add a couple of sentences about your understanding of what the C code does. It's a rather peculiar function. (In particular, I'm wondering whether the reversal of `a` and `b` in the first recursive call is intentional.)

Comment: @Hitori: this task is not for you. My best advice is... take a day or two and first learn how python arrays work.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to imitate the pointer, you could add another variable `i` to count your position in the array. Then you can also change the content of your array/list.

```
def rec(n, a, b, i):
    if n == 1:
        a[i] = b[i]
        return b[i]
    else:
        return rec(n // 2, b, a, i) + rec((n + 1) // 2, a, b, i + n // 2)

a = [5, 9, 9, 6, 4, 0]
b = [1, 7, 2, 9, 2, 0]

print(rec(5, a, b, 0))

>>> 27
```

Answer (score 0):

in python you can't use an assignment within the return. Some people talked about this here:
[How to assign a variable in IF, and then return it. (Python)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1550134/how-to-assign-a-variable-in-if-and-then-return-it-python)
So, just do:

```
a = b
return a
```

Comment: but in this case, that's the same as `return b`... and _may_ not actually translate the C code correctly (since it doesn't modify the inputs the way the C code does).

Comment: That won't work for arrays, list and other type of objects. The assignment is also done reference-wise

Answer (score 0):

if you want a boolean answer then it's a==b

otherwise

```
    def rec(n, a, b):
          if n == 1:
             a=b
             return a
```

Answer (score 0):

It's giving the error because of when you did this else part:

```
    else :
        return rec(n / 2, b, a) + rec((n + 1) / 2, a + n / 2, b + n / 2)
```

Note the second call to rec in the else part, note the arguments, especially the second and third argument. You are actually adding or '+' ing, in this case python thinks you are concatenating as a and b are lists, which is invalid, because n is an integer. So n/2 returns an integer, and a and b being lists, 
 a + n/2 or b + n/2 does not make sense!!