# Best way to iterate search terms conditionally and in order using python

Tags: python, if-statement

**Update**: The question has been revised, more info can be read just before and after the large code example.

---

Consider the following list of search terms:

```python
searchterms = {'term1': address, 'term2': name, 'term3': 'coordinates'}
```

where all can be 'nan' (np.nan in DataFrame) or contain some valid search term.

And say I have a function:

```python
def askGoogle(term):
    # return query result or skip to next
```

how would I in the best and most efficient way start with term1, if the term is `nan` or  server returns `NotFound` -  try the next, until one returns a result or all is `nan` or `NotFound`.

So far I have ended up with an enormous if elif else block of horror (I'll save you the hassle, it's 7 levels deep).

I'm new to python, but isn't there some short way of doing this? Maybe some recursive function?

Note: I've tried to search both here and google, but I really don't know what to search for.

**EDIT**: `nan` is from `pd.DataFrame` (`np.nan`) and `NotFound` *(actually, it's `"ZERO_RETURNS"`)* is returned from the server if the search term didn't give anything. It didn't come out properly above, but it is imperative that the terms are tried in order.

**EDIT2**: here is the code I started out with *(cleaned up for readability)*:

```
query = ''
    if not term1 == 'nan' or not term2  == 'nan' or not term3 == 'nan' :
        if not term1 == 'nan':
            if not term2 == 'nan':
                if not term3 == 'nan': # All found.
                    query = askGoogle(term1, self.queryParams(term1))
                        if query['status'] == 'NotFound':
                            query = askGoogle(term)
                                if query['status'] == 'NotFound':
                                    query = askGoogle(term)
                                else:
                                    query = askGoogle(term)
                            else:
                                query = askGoogle(term)
                    else: # Only term2 and term1 found.
                        query = askGoogle(term)
                            if query['status'] == 'NotFound':
                                query = askGoogle(term)
                                if query['status'] == 'NotFound':
                                    query = askGoogle(term)
                                else:
                                    query = askGoogle(term)                     
                else:
                    if not term3 == 'nan': #  Only term1 and term3 found.
                        query = askGoogle(term)
                        if term2
                        query = askGoogle(term)
                    else: # Only term1
                        term1 = askGoogle(term)
            elif not term2 == 'nan': # Only term2 and term3 found.
                if not term3 == 'nan':
                    term2 = askGoogle(term)
                    if not term2:
                    term3 = askGoogle(term)
                else: # Only term2 found
                    term2 = askGoogle(term)
            elif not term3 == 'nan': # term3 found
                term3 = askGoogle(term)
        else:
            query = 'All terms this loop is exhausted, nothing found'
```

It is obviously not working, I just crashed before I could finalize it.

---

**Update**: What I was initially looking for, and that I was oblivious of, was a way to set a variable directly in the `if` like this:

```python
if term = askGoogle(term) != 'ZERO_RESULTS':
    return term
```

However, this is [**not possible**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1550134/how-to-assign-a-variable-in-if-and-then-return-it-python#1551223) using python.
Instead, with help from [@alexbhandari](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/2826818/alexbhandari), I ended up with the following code:

```python
import numpy as np

def askGoogle(self, type, terms):
    query = ''
    for term in terms:
        if type == 1: 
            self.setParams(self.queryParams(term))
            self.setCallType('textsearch')
        elif type == 2: 
            self.setParams(self.detailsParams(term))
            self.setCallType('placeid')
        if term != np.nan:
            query = json.loads(requests.get(url=self.url, params=self.params))
            if query['status'] == 'OK':
                break
    return query
```

Which I then can call using:

```python
resp = askGoogle(x, [term1, term2, term3])
```

**NOTE**: the numbering is to differentiate between different types of API calls. It's running, and I think I got it right now.

Comment: When you say 'nan' or 'NotFound' do you mean that the dictionary contains these as strings as a value associated with one of the keys or that the key is completely missing from the dictionary? Also are you only dealing with dictionary keys 'term1', 'term2', 'term3' or does this need to work for any number of terms?

Comment: Can you post the code that works with the elif statements so we can have a better idea of what you are dealing with?

Comment: I apologize for the confusion, `nan`comes from pd.DataFrame and `NotFound` comes from the Oracle if nothing was found on the search term. It is also imperative that the terms are tried in  the order they are in the list.

Comment: My gruesome try to make this work is also added

Comment: I see, in that case your term1 == 'nan' will not work, you need term1 == np.nan instead. Also now it looks like the terms are not in a dictionary anymore, which means you can't do a loop anymore. Are they individual variables? If so how do you populate them? We need to get them into a form that is easier to check in a loop if you want to make the code concise

Comment: Also this line and the following similar lines do not make sense: term1 = askGoogle(term1, self.detailsParams(term1)). You've already checked for term1 == np.nan (you said 'nan' but im assuming you'll fix this) and query for term1 == 'NotFound'. I see no point in this line and all the lines that follow. Also you want to return the term that satisfies these conditions right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you only need to check 3 variables, I would use an if, else if block. It ends up being pretty quick. Please note that this assumes your askGoogle(term1, self.queryParams(term1)) that I took from your question works properly and you've imported numpy as np.

```
def askOracle(term1, term2, term3):
    if term1 != np.nan and askGoogle(term1, self.queryParams(term1)) != 'NotFound':
        return term1
    elif term1 != np.nan and askGoogle(term1, self.queryParams(term1)) != 'NotFound':
        return term2
    elif term1 != np.nan and askGoogle(term1, self.queryParams(term1)) != 'NotFound':
        return term3
    else:
        return 'Nothing found'
```

Also note that this will run askGoogle() at least once for term one. To fix this you'll have to split the if statement into the two ifs for all three terms.

```
if term1 != np.nan:
    return term1
elif askGoogle(term1, self.queryParams(term1)) != 'NotFound':
    return term1
```

If you can place term1, term2, term3 in a list we can loop through the list making the code a bit shorter. Putting all the pieces together I came up with this. The below has also been updated to return the result of query instead of the term1 as this requirement was added in a comment.

```
l = [term1, term2, term3]

def askOracle(l):
    for term in l:
        if term != np.nan:
            return askGoogle(term, self.queryParams(term))
        query = askGoogle(term, self.queryParams(term))
        if query != 'NotFound':
            return query
    return 'Nothing found'
```

then call the method by passing the list `l` like so `askOracle(l)`

**Old Answer (before question was revised and the fact that a dictionary is not used was clarified in the comments):**

Firstly, I wanted to note that dictionaries are not ordered in python (before python 3.6, as noted by @johnashu) so you cannot loop through the keys and values in the dictionary in order, which could have been a nice solution otherwise.

For the answer below I am assuming that when you say nan and notFound you mean the dictionary contains the strings 'nan' and 'NotFound'. If you are looking for whether 'term1' is actually a key in the dictionary or completely missing this can be done by replacing the if statement with a try, catch block when accessing the dictionary.

```
def askOracle(searchterms):
    for i in range(1,4):
        value = searchterms['term%d'%i]
        if(value != 'nan' and value != 'NotFound'):
            return value
    return 'All elements nan or NotFound'
```

Comment: I have made an edit to the question as per your request :)

Comment: Thanks! This seems to change some of the information I was assuming. Specifically the dictionary part. We can still do this in a loop. We would check term1 and if it is np.nan or NotFound then we could run askGoogle(term1, self.queryParams(term1)) and then loop for all the terms. We just need to load the terms into a list, which is why I asked about how to populate the term variables above. Also want to confirm that NotFound is of type string when returned from the server.

Comment: I updated my answer to reflect the changes in your question. Let me know how this works...

Comment: Thank you for taking your time on this, your solution looks very close to what I want, except I need to return the result from askGoogle(), not the term itself. If you could implement that in your answer, I think we are at a closure here :)

Comment: I went ahead and updated the for loop section of my answer since it is a quick fix. You should be able to figure this out and it might be a good exercise to try on your own first :) In the future, try to include all these key points (need to return result of the query, need to check for np.nan and the string 'NotFound') in your original question since each update takes time and makes the post a bit more cluttered

Comment: Also what is the point of checking that term1 != np.nan if you're going to run the query anyway to return the result? Why not just check `askGoogle(term1, self.queryParams(term1)) != 'NotFound'` right away and skip the np.nan?

Comment: I know, it's because I didn't really know how to ask the question properly, my apologies. Your solution is calling askGoogle() multiple times, and sending `nan` would not be efficient enough, since it will cause yet one more query to be made. I need to make that as sparingly as possible. I will look into this and share my findings once I'm sure I got it right. :)

Comment: My solution is only calling askGoogle once. The first time is inside an if, which returns so the second instance will be skipped. To make it to the second askGoogle() the if has to be false meaning the first call will be skipped

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/166199/discussion-between-alexbhandari-and-ole-anders).

Answer (score 0):

You can simply iterate over the dictionary using a for loop:

```
def askOracle(dict):
    for v in dict.values():
        if v:
            return v

print(askOracle(searchterms))
```

This will return the first search term it reaches.. if not it will return `None`

Comment: How do I know they are checked one by one in order, and how do I check if they are 'nan' before I eventually send them into `askOracle()`?

Comment: Since Python 3.6 dictionaries remember the insertion order.  This means that when it comes to iterating it will iterate in order.. I took nan as 'None' or an empty .. @alexbhandari answer is spot on using numpy.nan.. It is why I asked for the elif statement block. good luck!